# JavaFx Button adds ellipsis when rendered on a E4 ToolControl

Tags: java, javafx, eclipse-rcp, e4, efxclipse

I've an E4 application which has a `ToolControl`, the class that handles the tool control creates a JavaFX button, for some reason the button adds ellipsis and I've no clue why.

[image: Fx Button ellipsis]

Here is the link to the sample application

https://github.com/SDSethia/ColoredButton.git

Comment: Are you talking about the radius around the corners of the button?

Comment: No, the "..." in the button, the text in my code is `FxButton (1)` but its rendered as `FxButton ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button needs a layout (I wrapped mine in an HBox) for it to render correctly. Here is the modified code

```
    final FXCanvas canvas = new FXCanvas(parent, SWT.NONE);
    button = new Button();
    button.setText("FxButton (1)");
    button.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #186dee; -fx-text-fill: white;");

    final HBox box = new HBox();
    box.getChildren().add(button);

    final Scene scene = new Scene(box);
    canvas.setScene(scene);
```

This solved the issue.

Comment: This probably works because the button is resized by the HBox.

Answer (score 0):

JavaFX shortens the label automatically, when the size of the control (a button in your case) is too small for the text. This is independent of E4. So if you increase the size of the button, the complete text will show.

I looked at your project and I am wondering why you are using the SWT renderers, although you want to use JavaFX!

If you want to use E4 + JavaFX I recommend to use the e(fx)clipse renderers. This tutorial should get you started: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Efxclipse/Tutorials/Tutorial4

Comment: I tried `button.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);` but the result is still the same

Comment: With `button.setMaxWidth` you are only setting the maximum (!) width, not the actual width. Try `button.setPrefWidth` or `button.setMinWidth`.